# Share data between XNA game and console app

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making an XNA game in which player interacts with many objects simultaneously. I'd like to be able to dump chunks of object arrays into backing console app which will hold the data until it's needed again. How do I do that?

---

I'm thinking of using virtual Ram drives to store temp data, it might be fast enough.

Comment: That's a bit unusual, have you thought about using a database or cache?

Comment: I'm not sure about the speed of any approach at this point, as I haven't actually tried anything. Looking for well known quick ways.

Comment: Can you post your constraints? What are you guided by? Performance? Memory usage? Can you have a small delay for restoring "dumped" objects?

Comment: Small delay is ok every now and then. Thing is there are about 5 million objects in array when it's time to dump. Not sure if it can even be done quickly. And such array would take up about 600MB.

Comment: Why are you dumping it at all?? Why not just keep it in the same process? You're going to need to be a lot more clear about what you're trying to achieve here. Because what you're asking for is pretty zany.

Comment: The game loads different amount of resources every time, so sometimes (pretty often actually) it gets dangerously close to getting out of memory. I'd like that to stop being a problem by swapping memory containing currently unused data, but keeping it in other app so it doesn't take long enough to make the game lag.

Comment: I agree this seems highly unusual.  Perhaps a better approach would be to perform a bit of "culling," such that only the objects being actively used are in memory, with a separate thread dedicated to "streaming" additional objects from a backing store (database, file system), as needed.